# Java matching loops

Tags: java, match

I am attempting to loop through some string arraylists to match elements, but I am getting an error that my arrays are not of the same length. I have one arraylist with a bunch of samples in it and a second with just a few samples. I wish to search through the the first arraylist while comparing and matching them to the values in the second. When I find the places that the two arraylists match I want to take the index of the first and apply it to a third, which holds the means that coordinate with the samples (which are stored in the first, as a reminder.) I have included code leading up to where the problem is, but have tried to keep it as concise as possible. *Essentially I am hoping someone could explain either the error I am getting, or a better way to compare them.*

```
//this is how they are declared
ArrayList<String> pit = new ArrayList<String>(); int h =0;
...etc...
//a file is read in
while((sLine=inpt.readLine())!=null){
      splitn=sLine.split(delim2);
      //splits the file into two different ArrayLists, names and means
      pit.add(splitn[0]); pit2.add(splitn[2]);
}
String b="mean"; int pitn = 0;
//remove column titles from those two lists
while(pitn<pit.size()){
     if(pit2.get(pitn).equals(b)){
        pit.remove(pitn); pit2.remove(pitn);
     }
     else{
          ++pitn;
     }
}
//match a pattern to the file names that were entered
ArrayList<String> sampleNum = new ArrayList<String>();          
for(String inp : filenames) {
     Matcher matt=patt.matcher(inp);
     while(matt.find()){
           if(matt.groupCount() >= 2) {
              //match the first part of the file name
              samplenum = matt.group(1);
              //match the second grouping to paneltype
              paneltype = matt.group(2);
           }
           //add sample names to another arraylist
           sampleNum.add(samplenum);
     }
    **//I wish to search through the pit values for a place where it matches sampleNum
    //Problematically I am getting an error
    //for the length of pit** 
     for(int inx=0;inx<pit.size();inx++){
        //if the value of pit equals the value of sampleNum
        if(pit.get(inx).equals(sampleNum.get(h))){
           //add the value, of the same index, from pit2 to the mncov arraylist
           mncov.add(pit2.get(inx));
           h++;
        }
     }
```

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

I am entering 2 files so this makes sense, because sampleNum is taken from the file names. 2 files = 2 file names

```
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at consistentbelow.ConsistentBelow.main(ConsistentBelow.java:**72**)
```

Line **72** is this line:

> (pit.get(inx).equals(sampleNum.get(h))){

So I am not at all sure what is the problem here. I feel like I am missing something kind of obvious but have mulled on it to the point of blindness. I THINK that I gave enough info to get some help but I wouldn't bemoan giving some more if it would be helpful.

Comment: So, basically if the second term in the String is "mean" you remove the two parts? (In the first half of the code.)

Comment: @eboix if there is the String "mean" then I remove that value and the value where it matches in the other arraylist, because that value would be a string "SampleNum" and I just want the actual means and actual sample numbers, not the column names.

Comment: Okay. And `patt` is some predefined pattern, right?

Comment: @eboix yes, I printed it out to make sure that the pattern is working, and it is. The only problem seems to occur on the line '72' which is trying to match the values of pit.get(inx) and sampleNum.get(h). The error says the arrays are not the same length but I didn't think that it would cause any error.

Comment: KDiTraglia's solution fixes this particular problem. But are you sure that `matt.group(1)` and `matt.group(2)` will work? I just read the spec and I don't think that they'll cut off at spaces, rather at places were the regex is satisfied. For example, with a pattern like `a*`, you would get an empty String: `""` from `matt.group()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()

Comment: One last comment, your code won't always work unless both the filename and pit inputs are sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not a problem of the size of `pit` but of the size of `sampleNum`.  You are incrementing `h` every time you find a match, but have nothing stopping h from incrementing higher than the total length of sampleNum (ie everything has matched and it keeps trying to match).  A quick fix may be something like this

```
for(int inx=0; inx<pit.size() && h < sampleNum.size(); inx++){
    if(pit.get(inx).equals(sampleNum.get(h))){
       //add the value, of the same index, from pit2 to the mncov arraylist
       mncov.add(pit2.get(inx));
       h++;
    }
}
```

Not the most elegant fix but should eliminate the error I believe.  I also suspect this might not have exactly the output you are expecting, but hard to say without a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not going to make another answer because this one is fine. But maybe this is more elegant: `for(int inx=0; inx<pit.size() && h < sampleNum.size(); inx++){` This way you avoid an error if `sampleNum.size()` is zero.

Comment: Ah, so you are including both arraylist sizes, I see. Thank you for the explanation and all the help